# Django QuerySet filter on MySQL doesn't show properly

Tags: mysql, django

I working on mysql (5.6.38) and django 2.0.2 in my server. And I found this fault result:

```
>>> Tag.objects.filter(created__year=2018)
<QuerySet [<Tag: Tricks>, <Tag: Directory>, <Tag: Beginner>, <Tag: API>, <Tag: DRF>, <Tag: Flask>, <Tag: Solution>, <Tag: SSO>, <Tag: Multi Databases>, <Tag: Ajax>, <Tag: Internationalization>, <Tag: Multi Languages>, <Tag: Looping>, <Tag: Security>, <Tag: Internet>, <Tag: Templates>, <Tag: Problem>, <Tag: Database>, <Tag: Settings>, <Tag: Module>, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>
>>> 
>>> t = Tag.objects.first()
>>> t.created.year
2018
>>> t.created.month
7
>>> 
>>> sum([True for t in Tag.objects.filter(created__year=2018) if t.created.month == 7])
27
>>>
>>> # Why this queryset doesn't work?
>>> Tag.objects.filter(created__year=2018, created__month=7)
<QuerySet []>
>>> 
>>> # This queryset also
>>> Tag.objects.filter(created__year=2018).filter(created__month=7)
<QuerySet []>
>>>
```

But if I try with `django.db.models.Q`, it's working fine:

```
>>> from django.db.models import Q
>>> Tag.objects.filter(Q(created__year=2018) | Q(created__month=7)).distinct()
<QuerySet [<Tag: Tricks>, <Tag: Directory>, <Tag: Beginner>, <Tag: API>, <Tag: DRF>, <Tag: Flask>, <Tag: Solution>, <Tag: SSO>, <Tag: Multi Databases>, <Tag: Ajax>, <Tag: Internationalization>, <Tag: Multi Languages>, <Tag: Looping>, <Tag: Security>, <Tag: Internet>, <Tag: Templates>, <Tag: Problem>, <Tag: Database>, <Tag: Settings>, <Tag: Module>, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>
>>>
```

Here is my `models.py`

```
class TimeStampedModel(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Tag(TimeStampedModel):
    title = models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(_('Slug'), max_length=200, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_posts(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(tags=self).published()

    @property
    def total_posts(self):
        return self.get_posts().count()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            if slugify(self.title) != self.slug:
                self.slug = generate_unique_slug(Post, self.title)
        super(Tag, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Detail Tag')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Tags')
        ordering = ['-created']
```

> However, this queryset is ***working fine*** when I try on local mode.

Comment: can you show your model?

Comment: @HemanthSP I updated it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found this solution, I change `USE_TZ` to `False` and it's working fine.

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Jakarta'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = False
```

Because, If I want to use the timezone on MySQL, I should install this module:  *[mysql_tzinfo_to_sql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html)* first:

```
sudo mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo/ | mysql -u root mysql
```